# sending mailchimp campaign in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp

I'm trying to send a mail chimp campaign using asp.net, actually i created successfully the campaign and i can see it through my profile but also i want to send it through my code here is my code so if any one can help!!

```
private static void CreateCampaignAndSend(string apiKey, string listID)
        {
            Int32 TemplateID = 0;
            string campaignID = string.Empty;



            // compaign Create Options
            var campaignCreateOpt = new campaignCreateOptions
                                        {
                                            list_id = listID,
                                            subject = "subject",
                                            from_email = "cbx@abc.com",
                                            from_name = "abc",
                                            template_id = TemplateID
                                        };

            // Content

            var content = new Dictionary<string, string>
                              {
                                  {"html", "Lots of cool stuff here."}
                              };

            // Conditions
            var csCondition = new List<campaignSegmentCondition>();
            var csC = new campaignSegmentCondition {field = "interests-" + 123, op = "all", value = ""};

            csCondition.Add(csC);

            // Options
            var csOptions = new campaignSegmentOptions {match = "all"};


            // Type Options
            var typeOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                  {
                                      {"offset-units", "days"},
                                      {"offset-time", "0"},
                                      {"offset-dir", "after"}
                                  };

            // Create Campaigns

            var campaignCreate = new campaignCreate(new campaignCreateInput(apiKey, EnumValues.campaign_type.plaintext, campaignCreateOpt, content, csOptions, typeOptions));
            campaignCreateOutput ccOutput = campaignCreate.Execute();
            campaignSendNow c=new campaignSendNow();
            List<Api_Error> error = ccOutput.api_ErrorMessages;  // Catching API Errors


            if (error.Count <= 0)
            {
                campaignID = ccOutput.result;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Api_Error ae in error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n ERROR Creating Campaign : ERRORCODE\t:" + ae.code + "\t ERROR\t:" + ae.error);

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Finally i figured that I have to use campaignSendNowInput and campaignSendNow then execute the campaignSendNow and every thing works fine thanks to ALLAH.

Comment: which is the final code working? using only ***campaignSendNow*** ?